# Заменить регистр буквы в javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

Говорят, вот этот код должен делать из маленькой буквы большую.

```
function my_inp($event){
    document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = document.getElementById('inp2').value;
    var x = ($event.keyCode || $event.which);
    var x_char = String.fromCharCode(
    if(x_char=='a') 
    var x_char = x_char.replace('a', 'A');

}
```

У меня не работает, наверное я не то что-то написал. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Так это вы написали или кто-то другой? Если вы, то кто кроме вас может знать, что код должен делать?

Comment: Что-то там со скобками... `String.fromCharCode(` не заркывается....

Comment: синтаксическая ошибка в коде, скорее всего так должен был быть `x`: `String.fromCharCode(x)`

Comment: Менять-то может, он меняет. Но уж точно результат никуда не выносит.... И еще, а Вы уверены, например, что меняете русскую букву "а" в анлийском тексте (или наоборот)?

Comment: и да, этот код делает из маленькой `a` большую.

Comment: Сумасшедший код) Прям из базуки по воробьям) У вас несколько ошибок, но как минимум напишите, что вам надо получить.

Comment: @AleksanderK., в заголовке: _Заменить регистр буквы в javascript_ :-D

Comment: Да не, код, более-менее рабочий. Просто автор результат никуда не выводит, и кажется, что ничего не происходит...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Режим "Телепат" - ON*

```js
function my_inp($event) {
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('inp').value.replace(/a/g, 'A');
}

document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener('keyup', my_inp);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var x_char = String.fromCharCode(
> ```

```
var x_char = String.fromCharCode(x);
```

Ну и дальше надо бы что-то сделать, а то поменял символ и забыл про него...